# How do I change the language of the routing instructions in Here Maps Js api?

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I am using this example to generate the route from A to B.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b

But I can't find a way to change the language of the instructions (to portuguese).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your route request you can pass in the language parameter. For the language, you have two choices of Portuguese – Brazil that you can specify with `pt-br`, or Portuguese – Portugal that you can specify with `pt-pt`:

```
routeRequestParams = {
    routingMode: 'fast',
    lang: 'pt-br',
    transportMode: 'car',
    origin: '52.5160,13.3779', // Brandenburg Gate
    destination: '52.5206,13.3862',  // Friedrichstraße Railway Station
    return: 'polyline,turnByTurnActions,actions,instructions,travelSummary'
};
```